# How do I fill a row based on the number of filled columns in the row above?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Here's my current spreadsheet:

[image: data]

Rows 1 and 3 are the input, and I want to fill row 4 automatically based on how many columns there are in row 3. Example end result:

[image: discount factor for 3 years]

The "discount factor" is just `(1 + (DiscountRate/100)) ^ n`, where `n = 1` underneath the first cash flow, `n = 2` underneath the second cash flow, etc. I want the "discount factor" row to be automatically filled based on how many cash flows there are. So if I add another column of data to row 3, row 4 should automatically populate its column as well:

[image: discount factor for 4 years]

Which spreadsheet formulas can I use to automatically fill row 4 based on the number of filled columns in row 3?

Comment: Try this formula: =(1 + ($B$1/100))^COLUMN(A1)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel O365, you can use this formula:

```
B4: =(1+(Discount_rate/100))^SEQUENCE(,COUNT($3:$3))
```

Because of the dynamic array feature, it will automatically spill right as far as there are entries in row 3.

This assumes that the only entries in Row 3 are a label in A3, and cash flows in the subsequent columns.

[image]